# IBInspectable not recognized when using NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, interface-builder, bridging

I have a custom Objective-C class that contains two `CGFloat`s:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat minimumConstant NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat maximumConstant NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
```

Both are marked as `IBInspectable`. In the initializer of the class I set both bot `NaN` as I need to represent a difference between *0* and *nothing*. To make the class nice to use from Swift I marked both properties as `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` and created a Swift extension with the refined implementation:

```
@IBInspectable public var minimumConstant: CGFloat? {
    get {
        let constant = __minimumConstant
        return constant.isNaN ? nil : constant
    }
    set {
        if let constant = newValue {
            __minimumConstant = constant
            return
        }
        __minimumConstant = CGFloat.nan
    }
}

@IBInspectable public var maximumConstant: CGFloat? {
    get {
        let constant = __maximumConstant
        return constant.isNaN ? nil : constant
    }
    set {
        if let constant = newValue {
            __maximumConstant = constant
            return
        }
        __maximumConstant = CGFloat.nan
    }
}
```

This works great when using my class from code. When using Swift `NaN` will be mapped to `nil` and I can use optional unwrapping as usual.

The issue is that **as soon as I add `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` the Interface Builder will no longer recognize my properties as `IBInspectable`** and does not show them.

Is this a known issue? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You haven't posted the code that uses *@IBDesignable*! It's a different designation than *@IBInspectable*. :-)

Comment: Apologies. That was a mistake in my original question. There is no `IBDesignable` in this example. I meant `IBInspectable` and got the two mixed up. I updated my question .